# Maintaining a program folder in program files out of date?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

For the program I'm writing in vs C# wpf I need to store some user related information on the user's computer. As far as I knew this has almost always been done by creating a folder in C:\Program Files and adding whatever program related info to that folder in subfolders or whatever.  After doing some browsing I came across a lot of people saying that this method is out of date because sometimes access may be denied to create a folder there, it only works for administrative accounts, etc.. One site suggested saving to c:\users\username\appdata\roaming or c:\users\username\appdata\local. So my question is what is the best and most up to date method for saving program data to users computer?

Comment: Basically it has never been OK to store user stuff in Program Files, many programs just did that. Microsoft has quite good documentation about where to put what.

Comment: Why not just add a local db to the application itself?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils and where would you store the DB? That would just circle back to this question.

Comment: @codran, no it doesn't. The db is *intended* to be local to the application and MS/VS ensure it's in the proper place (e.g. not wherever you see fit).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this microsoft developer blog [Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files if I Target Multiple OS Versions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/):

Here is an example where you can store your **Local per user configuration files**

Configuration data files that the application uses and is unique per user.  It stays local to the individual machine and is not synchronized via Active Directory.

```
Example:    MyMachineSpecificData.xml
Windows 7:  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\<MyCompany>\<MyApp>
Vista:      %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\<MyCompany>\<MyApp>
XP:         %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\<MyCompany>\<MyApp>
```

So basically per user config files should go to:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\[Roaming,Local]
```

If those configs should be available to all users then:

```
%SystemDrive%\ProgramData
```

For per user data you can use [Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861346.aspx). For user independent access `C:\Users\Public`.

Additionally you can also use windows registry to store your configurations.

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\[Roaming,Local]` translates to `%APPDATA%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, so you don't have to calculate it yourself on each OS.

Comment: @codran good to know. I guess that running `set` in cmd will print all the environment variables right? Unfortunately I'm not using windows to verify that. But it seems like you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

It is mainly for UWP apps but you will have a general idea what to put where even if you are developing a WPF app.

You may need these folders:

- `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`
- `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`
- `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`